# PrivateRoute Flickering with my Firebase Auth Context

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a problem with flickering my private routes while using my AuthContext. Below is the code for my Private Route:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserAuth } from '../../Context/AuthContext';

const PrivateRoute =  ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = UserAuth();
  
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to='/login' />;
  }
  return children;
};


export default PrivateRoute;
```

No personal information shows, because the user is initialized to {} in Auth Context. but I can still see the page and navbar. Anyone have a solution?

Also, below is AuthContext.js:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../../firebase';

const UserContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

   const signIn = (email, password) =>  {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
   }

  const logout = () => {
      return signOut(auth)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      //console.log(currentUser);
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ createUser, user, logout, signIn }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that's kind of cheeky. I'm not going to post my solution, but basically, I wrapped the return statement `return children` in the PrivateRoute function with an if statement for a specific item in the user object. This prevents any return and 'solves' the flicker.